# Remove white gap spaces in the left and right sides

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap's [`panel-based`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_panels.htm) web page made using [`bootstrap's grid system`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). The problema is, I have those extra spaces in the left and right side of the divs. Basically the contents are on the center. How do I remove this?

I tried using margin-top, margin-left, margin-right, bootstrap's pull-left and pull-right, margin and padding set to 0, width:100% etc nothing worked.

Here's a picture:

[image]

Look at the left and right sides, thise the white spaces i'm trying to remove. I don't know if this is something wrong with my CSS or my bad use of framework (I'm new to it) or some bootstrap's standard behavior that I'm not aware of. But I'd like to what's this and know how to remove this.

Here's my HTML (this is the full HTML of above image except with the master page's HTML of course):

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <br />
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                       <div class="panel-heading">
                          <h3 class = "panel-title">JUST HAPPEND, YOU KNOW</h3>
                       </div>

                       <div class="panel-body">
                           <p />
                          <span class="date">15.40</span> CONTENTS GOES HERE... <p />
                          <span class="date">15.40</span> CONTENTS GOES HERE... <p />
                          <span class="date">15.40</span> CONTENTS GOES HERE... <p />
                          <span class="date">15.40</span> CONTENTS GOES HERE... <p />
                          <input class='btn btn-success' type='submit' value="LET ME READ ALL THAT" title="READ MORE...">
                       </div>
                   </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                 <div class = "panel panel-primary">
                       <div class = "panel-heading">
                          <h3 class = "panel-title">LAST NEWS</h3>
                       </div>
                       <div class = "panel-body">
                           <p />
                           MORE CONTENTS GOES HERE
                       </div>
                   </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class = "panel panel-primary">
                       <div class = "panel-heading">
                          <h3 class = "panel-title">VIDEOS</h3>
                       </div>
                       <div class = "panel-body">
                         <div class="vid">
                          <iframe width="420" height="315"
                              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yWP6Qki8mWc?cc_load_policy=1"
                              frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""
                           ></iframe>
                             </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
             </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
               <div class="panel panel-primary">
                       <div class = "panel-heading">
                          <h3 class = "panel-title">MAY I HELP YOU?</h3>
                       </div>
                       <div class = "panel-body">
                            HELLO
                       </div>
                    </div>
             </div>

          <div class="col-md-8">
                 <div class="panel panel-primary">
                       <div class = "panel-heading">
                          <h3 class="panel-title">THE LIFE</h3>
                       </div>
                       <div class = "panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="links">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Piugr0fCCpE/UZLhWealhpI/AAAAAAAACUU/UzB5PWn__oA/s1600/passaros0031.jpg" title="Image 1" data-gallery>
                                                <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Piugr0fCCpE/UZLhWealhpI/AAAAAAAACUU/UzB5PWn__oA/s1600/passaros0031.jpg"  alt="Image 1" class="img-responsive">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <a href="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-uk7UKQdsN5c/T_iX9EUDmuI/AAAAAAAABeA/4jpV4UmZjrM/s1600/passaros.jpg"  title="Image 2" data-gallery>
                                                <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-uk7UKQdsN5c/T_iX9EUDmuI/AAAAAAAABeA/4jpV4UmZjrM/s1600/passaros.jpg" alt="Image 2" class="img-responsive">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_sz2fJjO1XW8/TIwpeTIHrcI/AAAAAAAAE7I/z9fD9BTwWyA/s1600/passaro_001.jpg"  title="Image 3" data-gallery>
                                                <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_sz2fJjO1XW8/TIwpeTIHrcI/AAAAAAAAE7I/z9fD9BTwWyA/s1600/passaro_001.jpg" alt="Image 3" class="img-responsive">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
        <br /> <br />
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    AAAAAAA
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    BBBBBBB
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    CCCCCCC
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: A row in bootstrap is made of 12 columns. In your code I see 4 columns large as 4 and one large as 8, which means that in your row there are 4*4+8=24 columns. This is why you are getting those white spaces. To remove them you have to divide your columns in rows so that each row contains at most 12 columns

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/8f0s62uL/ as example

Comment: can you post the css to see why margin-top, margin-left, margin-right, bootstrap's pull-left and pull-right, margin and padding set to 0, width:100% do not work?

Comment: @silviagreen: I did the fix but this didn't remove the spaces.  I just tried each one but as none worked I removed them. None of them is part of my css right now.

Comment: If I copy and paste your html code in jsfiddle with bootstrap css there is no right and left white spaces, so I guess that there must be others css rules that "create" them.

Comment: I'm also guessing must be others css rules that create them. Any idea how to "debug" it?

Comment: Try to use tools like firebug or inspect element in your browser to identify which rule is causing the problem. Il you need help, you can create a jsfiddle with che css code so we can take a look too.

Comment: Try also to check using those tools if there are rule with higher priority (for example with !important), they may cause your rule like width:100% to be ignored

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure out what would be this rule, reading all the external css rules (even I haven't much experience at it) because I thought this was something I did wrong. But I think it's a bootstrap's default. I jsut created a new ASP.NET WebForms project (without any css created by myself) and copy-and-past exactly the HTML in the question and the page look like the same, with all white spaces in the sides. Look at the image http://prnt.sc/a418ij This is all the code of the page (I didn't even touch master page) http://pastebin.com/iMJCdRVu

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGaoQN still I do not see them...which external css are you using in this page? Can I see the master page?

Comment: I'm not using any external css. I did notice that in those jsfiddler and alike web sites, the page is fine. I don't know why. Here's the master page code: http://pastebin.com/gGPH2Fs8

Comment: This is css's contents folder: http://prnt.sc/a41mpb and site.css is http://pastebin.com/P5auEF9z

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking - do you want to make your page take the whole width of the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're trying to make your page full-width, rather than `1170px` wide and centered, which is what the `.container` bootstrap class does. If that is the case, all you need to do is replace `.container` with [`.container-fluid`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            foo, bar, foobar 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I don't see any `.container` declarations in your excerpt, the changes should occur in your master page. Also remember that the number of columns per each `.row` should always amount to 12 (2 x `.col-md-6`, 3 x `.col-md-4`, etc).

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbveWK)

Comment: The container is really in the master page. That page has a `<div class="container body-content">` I just replaced it by `<div class="container-fluid body-content">`. Is this the right place to replace, right? It worked fine, thank you so much

Comment: Yeap, that's the right place. I would even argue that you can also remove `.body-content` from the declaration so you get some left/right spacing. If this solution worked for you consider marking it as the answer. And you're welcome!

Comment: Is possible to get same effect as using `.container-fluid` and add some padding? my panel's borders hit the edges. There's even a horizontal scrollbar. I want  to just some padding, something like `.body-content` would provide nothing the big gap in the sides that I had before

Comment: Is this: `.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px !important;
    padding-right: 15px !important;
}` a hack?

Comment: Nope, it comes with the bootstrap templates in ASP.NET. Feel free to leave it in if it suits your purpose, I always remove it as I build my CSS rules in a way which makes those set of rules unnecessary.

Comment: Actually I was asking about the `!important;` that I added myself. I don't know if it's the proper way to workaroud the div hitting the edges since I'm using this with `.container-fluid`

Comment: See the structure of my CodePen link, I removed `.body-content` from the HTML altogether and the content isn't hitting the edges, Bootstrap takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: in bootstrap there is a rule

```
.container {
   width: 1170px;
}
```

This causes the white gaps. To remove it, simply add `width:100%` to `body-content` in site.css

```
/* Wrapping element */
/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px;
   width:100%; //ADD THIS
}
```

Here is the proof: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGaoQN)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time on this! On my local test `width:100%` rule didn't change anything. What really did was switch from `.container` to `.container-fluid` in master page's div. Like pointed out in @trashr0x 's answer

Comment: `.container` is a bootstrap class, while `.body-content` is not. Trying to modify the behavior of `.container` will only cause you trouble down the line. Let bootstrap take care of the plumbing for you, use `.container-fluid` ;)